# Xbox Live: Using several values in LeaderboardRow

Tags: leaderboard, xbox-live

Class LeaderboardRow has Values as IList, while Values[0] is normally used for storing a score value.

I want to store score value along with date-time when this score was obtained.

A quite obvious workaround would be keeping strings with zero-padded score, concatenated by timestamp.

However it will be more natural to involve two elements: Values[0] for the score value, Values[1] for the timestamp. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the creators program only supports a single value for leaderboard rows.